# wp_head for single post in loop

Tags: wordpress

I want to get post header in loop this return only first post header and after that return general site header how to make it return header for the post in loop

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
     the_post();
              wp_head();
    }
```

Comment: I think you don't understand what [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) does, and what a document header is.

Comment: OK can you please told me how to get header js and css for every post on loop ?

Answer (score 0):

By "Post header" - do you mean the actual post name? First of all, check the loop documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). When you query "the loop" you get a specific amount of posts from your database based on the query arguments. Displaying data from the loop is done separately inside the loop. for example:

```
<?php
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
         <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      } // end if
?>
```

The code above will query all your posts and display the title of the post that is a link to that post.

Comment: BY "Post header" I mean all js and css files for this post which located in wp_head

Comment: Well, if you have wp_head(); in your template header.php it's loaded across the whole site. Why do you actually want to load them again inside the <body> and inside the loop?